"How is the field_selection_filter field passed? (API Looker Update an Alert)
I am trying to make a change to a Looker alert via API, but I am encountering the following error:
PUT /alerts/49 (422: Unprocessable Entity) Seconds: 0.271
Body (325 bytes)
{
 "message": "Validation Failed",
 "errors": [
{
"field": "alert",
"code": "invalid",
"message": "field_selection_filter must contain :field_name",
"documentation_url": "https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/r/err/4.0/422/put/alerts/:alert_id"
 }
],
 "documentation_url": "https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/r/err/4.0/422/put/alerts/:alert_id"
}

My code:
{
  "applied_dashboard_filters": [
    {}
  ],
  "comparison_type": "GREATER_THAN",
  "cron": "1 4 * * *",
  "custom_url_base": "",
  "custom_url_params": "",
  "custom_url_label": "",
  "show_custom_url": false,
  "custom_title": "",
  "dashboard_element_id": "4300",
  "description": "",
  "destinations": [
    {
      "destination_type": "EMAIL",
      "email_address": "janderson5554910a@gmail.com"
      }
  ],
  "field": {
    "title": "Qualquer Contagem de Is Anomaly (Yes / No)",
    "name": "contagem_de_is_anomaly_yes_no",
    "filter": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  "followed": true,
  "followable": false,
  "is_disabled": false,
  "disabled_reason": "",
  "is_public": false,
  "investigative_content_type": "",
  "investigative_content_id": "",
  "lookml_dashboard_id": "",
  "lookml_link_id": null,
  "owner_id": "11",
  "owner_display_name": "Janderson",
  "threshold": 0,
  "time_series_condition_state": {
    "previous_time_series_id": "",
    "latest_time_series_id": ""
  }
}

This field called field_selection_filter does not appear in the example provided by Looker and I don't know how to use it. Does anyone know how this field is passed in the request?
I followed the steps that were described in the Looker Update an Alert API documentation. After encountering the problem described, I did a Google search to find out what the field_selection_filter field is, which apparently is a field that is used to specify which data should be considered or filtered when creating or updating an alert. However, I could not find an example or explanation of how to use this field anywhere. I tried putting it inside the field, outside the field, and even inside applied_dashboard_filters, all without success.
I hope to find an example or explanation of how to use this field in the Looker request.
